# I want count person per age

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table who has many columns and up to 1 million records.
I want count person per age and per service_name.

My table columns is like:

```
birthdate     person_id       service_name
-----------------------------------------------
1989/12/02    123456789       sql_server
1984/11/22    548321697       developer_server
1983/12/02    685221698       texas_server
1989/05/02    845132023       network_server
1986/05/15    210254638       sad_server
1990/03/22    853612045       happy_server
     .                 .                  .
     .                 .                  .
     .                 .                  .
     .                 .                  .
     .                 .                  .
```

Comment: If `birthdate` is defined as a `varchar2` column as suggested in comments then the problem becomes much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How precise do you want age to be? Birth Year? Full Years? Something more precise?
Is your birthday Column an Oracle DATE type?

Assuming it is a DATE then you need something like this to get full years:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ( SYSDATE - birthdate ) YEAR TO MONTH ) AS age
     , service_name
     , COUNT( 1 ) AS person_count
    FROM my_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ( SYSDATE - birthdate ) YEAR TO MONTH )
       , service_name;
```

Comment: THANK YOU.all column is varchar2 and I want AGE and birth date is a column in my oracle database. The problem description is find number of person in one age(like 29 years old) and on servicename (like network_server).